# Ubuntu OS recovery – accidentally deleted ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 from /lib64 folder in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-14.04, data-recovery, rm

I was remotely working on the machine with SSH but after deleting the ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 file by mistake I closed the ssh session and now I cannot login because it gives me following error:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-32-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

21 packages can be updated.
16 updates are security updates.

Last login: Sat Apr  2 02:52:19 2016 from *****
/bin/bash: No such file or directory
Connection to <machine-ip> closed.
```

Is there a way through which I can login and put the ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 in /lib64 folder from some other ubuntu machine or using live cd?

### EDIT

After some investigation in some other Ubuntu 14.04 machine I came to know that the ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 on /lib64 a symbolic link to `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so`. Output of `ls -l /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Feb 25  2015 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
```

The porblem is I am not able to login because `/bin/bash` is not being identified. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have an actual console access, instead of SSH?

Comment: @Massimo yes I can get access to the physical machine.

Answer (score 3):

Boot the system from a live CD, mount the root partition, copy the missing file from the CD to where it should be; reboot and you should be ok.

If the file you need is not present on the CD (f.e. due to a version mismatch), you'll need to get it from another running system or from the Ubuntu package repository.